# Alamofire request parameters as Collection of Dictionaries [[String:Any]] instead a Dictionary [String:Any]

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

There is a question that i'd been thinking about for sometime now, here is the thing, i'd had the case when some of the apis that i am consuming require that the post parameters to be a simple array of objects (in this case dictionaries) however the parameters alias in Alamofire is a Dictionary of `[String:Any]` kind, would it be possible to send and array of dictionaries `[[String:Any]]`instead a dictionary? Shall i create a feature request about it?

thanks in advance for your responses.

Comment: I'd support this feature request. I have a similar situation, with an API I created which is also an array of Dictionary type objects. This is possible with networking libraries for Android, but it seems the networking libraries for iOS (at least for Swift) are not as mature.

Comment: Then looks like i'll have to create the feature request!, thanks for your support